# How to detect Oracle database shutdown in JDBC?

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc

In an application, we have used JDBC to connect to Oracle database. We have attached. The issue is to identify through a callback/listener, that the database was shutdown.

Currently, we have the the following listener attached:

```
Connection eventListener = new ConnectionEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void connectionErrorOccurred(ConnectionEvent event){
        // log - connection error
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionClosed(ConnectionEvent event) {
        // log - connection closed
    }
}
```

None of this events are triggered when the database is shutdown.

The idea is to **detect the database shutdown** and then **the database start**, and have a mechanism to inform the users, and to either poll for the database (configurable) or suspend the service (the application).

Comment: what's your mean ?! when the connection failed to connect then maybe db is shutdown or something.

Comment: There is also a way to kill the session, while the db is not shutdown, doing the below:

    alter system kill session '<sid>,<serial#>'

Answer (score 0):

You can not properly specify the problem. You could only get connection or fail to get connection, the reason (unable to connect, db shutdown etc) could not be specified, you gonna get same exceptions with all these cases.

Comment: I agree with you. Is there any other way, with which we can check whether the database is shutdown, and not that something is wrong with my connection. I understand (per my knowledge), that all I have the control on, is on the connection I have with the database.

Comment: @harshchiki as I know, there is no way to define what was wrong. I've tried to run even sql plus and cached code exceptions, however I've god for several different problems same code exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your request is not fully defined. For example in case of RAC cluster you might configure the application to respond to ONS messages, and your application can safely migrate all the connections to another database node. So even if one database node is down, your application can still work smoothly.

For brief overview look at JBOSS source code, there is a class called exception sorter, which lists various useful Oracle errors codes.
For [example](http://kickjava.com/src/org/jboss/resource/adapter/jdbc/vendor/OracleExceptionSorter.java.htm), but I think the current JBOSS'es code base has even longer list.

[Here](https://github.com/tora-tool/tora/blob/master/extlibs/trotl/src/trotl_error.cpp) is a list of error codes, I collected. All of the error codes express a situation, where connection to the database is not possible (for some reason).

PS: the DCD (dead connection detection) is a different topic.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a transaction so if you query fails, it will give you an error which you can then check the connection.